# RFID solution for reading multiple tags

Tags: raspberry-pi, microcontroller, rfid

I am working on a Robot-project where a sub task is have to check how many and which RFID-tags are placed in a bucket.

Multiple tags will be placed into the bucket - so I run into the problem with RFID-tags colliding with each other. The reader will be connected and programmed via Raspberry Pi. From my research so far I have come up with the following 3 options: 
[image]

**1** RFID reader at the buttom of the bucket. This has to be a reader able to read the multiple tags at the same time, since the tags will be laying on top of each other. Example of reader: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14066

**2** RFID reader on the side of the bucket. Should read the tags passing by as they are thrown into the bucket. Would not required that the RFID reader is able to read multiple tags at once, but the reading should be fast enough to catch them passing by. Example of reader: ADAFRUIT PN532 NFC/RFID

**3** Same concept as 2 but minimizing the space and using slides to hopefully give a bit longer time for reading the tags. Example of reader: Same as in 2

I am aiming for the most simple and most secure solution.

How would you guys do this, and what kind of RFID hardware would you recommend to go with the Raspberry Pi connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up going with setup 1 and using this RFID-reader from Sparkfun. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14066

I interface the reader by use of the Mercury library in a Python program. Super reliable reader I can highly recommend.